# About extending Fourier transform on Lp spaces.

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Schwartz class are dense in Lp spaces. We have the definition of Fourier transform in Schwartz class. So why we can't extend this definition to all of the space Lp?